# Module `@react-navigation/core` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

i've have a weird one with a react native project running both react-navigation and redux.

i need to add this package:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-redux-helpers

i ran:
`npm install react-navigation-redux-helpers`

then added this line to my code:

```
import { createNavigationReducer } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';
```

now whenever i run the project, it fails to compile with this error:

```
Module `@react-navigation/core` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

Anyone ran into something like this before?

I've tried removing node_modules folder and package.lock file.  then I tried clearing Watchman and NPM cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the node_modules folder and `react-navigation-redux-helpers` from `package.json`.

Go to the root directory of the project and remove the current node modules and install again.

```
rm -rf node_modules npm install
```